# LibreOffice Calc two Alignments - One Cell

Tags: format, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to write one word with left alignment and one word with right alignment in a single cell in LibreOffice Calc?

Like that: | normal Cell one | Halli _________ Hallo | normal Cell three |

Everytime I try to simulate it with many spaces between Halli and Hallo, there are format problems when I convert it to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Format the cell to have a distributed horizontal alignment [my LO 4.1.6.2 on Linux offer this option].
Stayed that way after exporting to PDF.

***This is not a programming question - use [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) for software handling questions next time, please.***